# How to control fan speed and temperatures on Asus A8Js laptop?

Tags: server, fan, asus

I have tried installing [asusfan](http://code.google.com/p/asusfan/) and lm-sensors but I'm unable to control my fans to cool my laptop down sufficiently. Currently it overheats at about 100 degrees celsius and my sensors output somehow does not have any fan information on it:

```
jackson@OLYMPIA:~$ sensors

acpitz-virtual-0

Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:       +69.0°C  (crit = +110.0°C)                  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:      +66.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)  

coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 1:      +66.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

I have checked my bios and there isn't any fan settings there. I can consistently overheat just by converting a video via Handbrake. I have ubuntu-desktop installed for a GUI.

Is there a way for me to control my fans to start spinning before it reaches a critical temperature and kills itself?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=42737) forum post might be of use to you. Beware: this is extremely in-depth.

[Here](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/13393/) is a brainstorm proposing easy fan speed control: